# SQL server connection issue using Spring

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I found an issue connecting my web application using JDBC or Spring to a SQL Server database (not Express).

At some point of my code I call:

```
this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);
```

and the application is running correctly but, it's waiting and doesn't proceed. The same happens with another web application with:

```
getJdbcTemplate().query(...)
```

If I take a look to the db using:

```
SELECT SPID, STATUS, PROGRAM_NAME, LOGINAME=RTRIM(LOGINAME), HOSTNAME, CMD
FROM MASTER.DBO.SYSPROCESSES
WHERE DB_NAME(DBID) = 'myDB' AND DBID != 0
```

I can see there is a connection opened but "AWAITING COMMAND". No exception is handled, it's just waiting for something.

The SQL Server Profiler for that connection (Audit login) returns:

```
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed
```

It works until some weeks ago. I think it should be something related to SQLServer configuration, but I'm quite sure I didn't change anything. We can exclude a firewall issue because the connection is correctly created. Anyone could help me, please?

Comment: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8988851/466862 if you are using Java 6 Update 29, or Java 7 / Java 7 Update 1, it might be the same problem

Comment: Tnx, it's 1.6.0_29, I'll try to update it (if available) or try with another JVM

Comment: This is the bug reference: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7105007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) it's a Java 1.6.0_29 bug.