# SQL Server JDBC Connection times out after upgrade to TIBCO TRA 5.7.4 (JRE 1.6.0_30)

Tags: java, jdbc, tibco, businessworks

After upgrading to TIBCO BusinessWorks (BW) 5.10 (most likely not related) and TIBCO Runtime Agent (TRA) 5.7.4, JDBC connections using the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServer - sqljdbc4.jar) times out. This happens for example in the TIBCO Designer when using "Test Connection" on a JDBC Connection.

Note that TRA 5.7.4 includes JRE 1.6.0_30.

Comment: Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986350/jdbc-connection-hangs-with-no-response-from-sql-server-2008-r2 except that it should be fixed with Java 1.6 update 30

Comment: Mark, it is related but just updating to 1.6u30 (which is done automatically when you update the TRA) isn't enough since it doesn't work out of the box after the update.

Comment: Aleksandr, is it correct to put the answer in the question? And if so why doesn't the SO interface do that automatically when you answer your own question?

Comment: No, you shouldn't include the answer in the question, so I have rolled back the edit by Aleksandr.

Comment: Sorry for that. Your answer seemed like additional info to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to resolve the problem:

1. Make sure that the JDBC driver is in your classpath for both BW and Designer by checking your .tra files (TIBCO_HOME\bw\5.10\bin\bwengine.tra and TIBCO_HOME\designer\5.7\bin\designer.tra). This could be done by dropping the driver .jar in TIBCO_HOME\tpcl\5.7\lib
2. Add the following line to your BW and Designer .tra files:

   java.property.TIBCO_SECURITY_VENDOR=j2se

You may also have to perform the above for other TIBCO software such as Hawk and Administrator, depending on your setup.